# Google Ads API fatal error function render

Tags: google-ads-api

When running V15 (or V14), of Google Ads API I get this error when I try to update ads, add new products etc. Same error in different functions. Any idea what can cause the error?

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function render() on null in google-ads-php\src\Google\Ads\GoogleAds\V15\Services\Client\AdGroupServiceClient.php:115
Stack trace:
#0 \google-ads-php\src\Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Util\V15\ResourceNames.php(224): Google\Ads\GoogleAds\V15\Services\Client\AdGroupServiceClient::adGroupName()
#1 \ads_functions\functions.php(584): Google\Ads\GoogleAds\Util\V15\ResourceNames::forAdGroup()
#2 \ads_functions\functions.php(625): createListingGroupUnitBiddable()
#3 \adsapi\adwords_subdivide_pla.php(621): createItems()
#4 \adsapi\adwords_subdivide_pla.php(85): SubdividePla::runExample()
#5 \adsapi\adwords_subdivide_pla.php(904): SubdividePla::main()
#6 {main}
```